# How to show Area chart behind a column chart - extjs (multi-chart)

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts, extjs4

Hie,
Im working on ExtJS 4 charts.

I want to have a column chart and area chart together.
I did render these together, but the problem is - the area chart is placed over the column chart.

I'm looking for some attribute/hack, that will render the area chart BEHIND the column chart!

Sorry, I cannot place the actual code here, as i've implemented fusebox framework, so many things had to be configured.

Sample code from the extJS examples will suffice,(thanks for your time)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

They render by order. If you first define Area Chart and then define Column Cahrt in the Series part it should work.

```
series: [{
    type: 'area',
    axis: 'left',
    xField: 'yourxField',
    yField: 'youryField'
}, {
    type: 'column',
    axis: 'left',
    xField: 'yourxField',
    yField: 'youryField'
}]
```